# discord js 14 slashcommand embed

Tags: discord.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, CommandInteraction, EmbedBuilder, Client } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data:new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("createEmbed")
        .setDescription("Create new test Embed!"),
    /**
     * 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
     * @param {Client} client
     */

    async excute (interaction, client) {
        const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(0x0099FF)
        .setTitle('Some title')
        .setAuthor({ name: 'Some name' })
        .setDescription('Some description here')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        )
        .addFields({ name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true })
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: 'Some footer text here' });

        await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [exampleEmbed]
        });
    },
};
```

console
D:\감기여요\visual studio code\discord_bot\test_discord_bot\node_modules@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:76
throw this.error;
^

ExpectedConstraintError: Invalid string format
at Object.run (D:\감기여요\visual studio code\discord_bot\test_discord_bot\node_modules@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1564:64)    at D:\감기여요\visual studio code\discord_bot\test_discord_bot\node_modules@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:142:66
at Array.reduce ()
at StringValidator.parse (D:\감기여요\visual studio code\discord_bot\test_discord_bot\node_modules@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:142:29)
at Object.validateName (D:\감기여요\visual studio code\discord_bot\test_discord_bot\node_modules@discordjs\builders\dist\interactions\slashCommands\Assertions.cjs:11:17)
at MixedClass.setName (D:\감기여요\visual studio code\discord_bot\test_discord_bot\node_modules@discordjs\builders\dist\interactions\slashCommands\mixins\NameAndDescription.cjs:9:16)
at Object. (D:\감기여요\visual studio code\discord_bot\test_discord_bot\commands\createembed.js:5:10)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module.*extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
constraint: 's.string.regex',
given: 'createEmbed',
expected: 'expected /^[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\p{N}\p{sc=Devanagari}\p{sc=Thai}*-]+$/u.test(expected) to be true'
}

I've tried countless methods, but all of them have the same result.

Any good ideas?

I am new to programming

Answer (score 1):

Command names cannot contain upper case letters. `createEmbed` has a capital E which is in violation of the constraint as described by the regex. Rename `createEmbed` to something else like `create-embed`.